# How do I select all rows in a MySQL column

Tags: mysql

This seems to be an easy question but I can't for the life of me find an answer. How do I select all rows in a column regardless of value? For instance if I want everything in the column location:

```
"SELECT * FROM whateverTable WHERE id='$id' AND date='$date' AND location='I don't care, return everything'"
```

Keep in mind that I need location in there because I'm getting a dynamic URL query to this database, otherwise I would have just left it out.

***Edit***
I've read some of the answers and shame on me for not making myself clearer. I'm trying to see if a MySQL query where you can select every row in a column is possible without the need for this:

```
if ($location == '') {
  "SELECT * FROM whateverTable WHERE id='$id' AND date='$date'"
} else {
  "SELECT * FROM whateverTable WHERE id='$id' AND date='$date' AND location='$location'"
}
```

Rather than hacking up my code like that (because I have a hell of alot more query clauses in my real code), I'm trying to see if something like this is possible :

```
"SELECT * FROM whateverTable WHERE id='$id' AND date='$date' AND location='%'"
```

or this:

```
"SELECT * FROM whateverTable WHERE id='$id' AND date='$date' AND location='.*'"
```

But I'm not having any luck. If it's not, I'll just move on. Sorry for not making myself clearer

Comment: The WHERE clause doesn't have to reference every column.

Comment: You should probably avoid this route all together and add another method to retrieve data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said in your question, you should build the query dynamically and just omit that field. The query would then become:

```
SELECT * FROM whateverTable
WHERE id = '$id'
AND date = '$date'
```

If you can't do that for some reason, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM whateverTable
WHERE id = '$id'
AND date = '$date'
AND (location='$location' OR '$location' = '')
```

Setting `$location` to the empty string will cause all locations to be returned.

<sub>And don't forget to correctly escape your strings to avoid SQL injection attacks.</sub>

Comment: Logically, I though setting location to '' would return every row, but it's not returning any row for some reason

Comment: @JohnBowlinger: You need to add `OR '$location' = ''`. Without that part it will only match rows where the location is the empty string, which is not what you want.

Comment: I am trying this in my workbench but no luck. what exactly is $ sign used for?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT location FROM whateverTable` will return you every single row/value in the location column.

Add your where clause if you want to start filtering the results down.

Comment: for debugging purposes i use `mysqli_fetsh_array(mysqli_query('SELECT location FROM whateverTable'))` , then i display all results using foreach, but that only gives me the very first record in the column !

Answer (score 0):

If you're dynamically building the query just check if location is null or the empty string and then omit that part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Replace equal symbol : "=" by `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM whateverTable WHERE id='$id' AND date='$date' AND location LIKE '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a sub query?

```
SELECT * FROM whateverTable WHERE location IN (SELECT location FROM whateverTable);
```